# ImportError when using get_absolute_url

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a templatetag for getting the latest entries, but I can't seem to access the "get_absolute_url" function.

My error is

```
No module named app2 (not the name of the app I'm trying to use)
```

My newsmodel is like this:

```
STATUS_CHOICES = (
    (DRAFT, _('Draft')),
    (HIDDEN, _('Hidden')),
    (PUBLISHED, _('Published'))
)

TYPE_CHOICES = (
    ('normal', _('Normal')),
    ('special', _('Special')),
)


class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255)
    body = RichTextField(null=True, blank=True)
    start_publication = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_publication = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)    
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=DRAFT)
    arttype = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default='normal', )

    objects = models.Manager()
    published = EntryPublishedManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-start_publication']
        get_latest_by = 'creation_date'


    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
            creation_date = timezone.localtime(self.start_publication)
            return ('entry_detail', (), {
                'year': creation_date.strftime('%Y'),
                'month': creation_date.strftime('%b').lower(),
                'day': creation_date.strftime('%d'),
                'slug': self.slug})
```

My urls.py is like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', DateDetailView.as_view(allow_future=True, date_field='start_publication', queryset=Entry.objects.all()), name='entry_detail'),
)
```

My templatetag latest_news.py:

```
from django import template
from apps.news.models import Entry


register = template.Library()

def show_news():
        entry = Entry.published.filter(arttype='normal').order_by('-start_publication')[:4]
        return entry

register.assignment_tag(show_news, name='latest_news')
```

My frontpage.html template:

```
{% latest_news as latest_news %}
{% for entry in latest_news %}
    <h2>{{ entry.title }}</h2>
    <p><a href="{{ entry.get_absolute_url }}">Read more</a></p>
{% endfor %}
```

{{ entry.title }} is working fine. But not .get_absolute_url. Why is it trying to import another app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `get_absolute_url` you forgot to call `reverse` on the url. You are passing the tuple back which is makes it invalid. Your `get_absolute_url` should be:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def get_absolute_url(self):
        creation_date = timezone.localtime(self.start_publication)
        return reverse('entry_detail', kwargs={
            'year': creation_date.strftime('%Y'),
            'month': creation_date.strftime('%b').lower(),
            'day': creation_date.strftime('%d'),
            'slug': self.slug})
```

[`permalink` decorator is deprecated and the use of `reverse` is recommended](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#the-permalink-decorator)

Answer (score 0):

You have an error somewhere else in your project, in an app that is referenced in urls.py.

The reverse URL lookup functionality (which you've implicitly used by using the `@permalink` decorator) has to import all views referenced in your urls.py file in order to calculate the correct value. If you have an error somewhere, it will fail.

You should find the reference to `app2`, wherever it is, and fix it.

Comment: Yes, found my error, but I still needed to add reverse to my "get_absolute_url" for it to work.